# Plug For D-Hole

Tags: connector

Not exactly electronic design but hopefully acceptable enough to avoid closing...

I have sheet metal enclosure which has 3 D holes for SMA bulkhead connectors. It may be that only one or two of the three are actually used (a wireless option not installed). Rather than leaving an open hole giving an unprofessional appearance, I'd like to have some sort of plug. I've tried searching for such a product but can't find anything out there. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might used to maintain a professional appearance?

[image: D-holes]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Heyco hole plugs](http://www.heyco.com/Hole_Plugs/).

[image: D hole plug]

Answer (score 0):

They make rubber plugs that are designed to fill the holes

http://store.netgate.com/dustcap.aspx

[image]

Not recommending that vendor, just the first one I happened to come across.  They fit tightly enough that they won't easily come out accidentally, and should be quite cheap in bulk.